# Extract text from a ajax response which contains <tag>

Tags: javascript, ajax, text, extract

I have write a little piece of code to retrieve news from rss page. Here is the code :

```
this.loadRecentNews = function loadRecentNews() {
            $.get("http://rss.nytimes.com/services/xml/rss/nyt/GlobalHome.xml", function (data) {
                $(data).find("item").each(function () {
                    var el = $(this);

                    console.log("------------------------");
                    console.log("Title      : " + el.find("title").text());
                    console.log("Link     : " + el.find("link").text());
                    console.log("Description: " + el.find("description").text());
                    console.log("Date: " + el.find("pubDate").text());

                });
            });

        };
```

Here is the output :

```
Title : Example of title

Link : http://www.example.com

Description : Example of <<bb>>Description</b> containing <> tag..

Date : Example of date
```

My problem is that i want to extract only the text of the Description value to build a new Json object which contain this text.

How can i do to extract only the text without <> values ?

Comment: usually text() will do this. Can you paste in the xml from the rss?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you're using jQuery, you can use its `.text()` method.

```
var beforeText = "Example of <b>Description</b>" ;
var afterText = $("<p>").html(beforeText).text() ;
```

This uses jQuery to make a new HTML element (that is never added to the page) and update its innerHTML and then use `.text()` to get the text only.

Another (riskier) option is a regex to replace anything between `<` and `>` with an empty string:

```
var afterText = beforeText.replace(/<[^>]*>+/g, "")
```

Comment: Oh perfect ! It works !

I see just another problem, in afterText variable, sometimes there is 2 escape characher between two word. Any idea to adjust this ?

Comment: Which method are you using?

Comment: Fisrt method, using .text()

Comment: add `.replace(/<>/g,"")` to the end. Like so: `$("<p>").html(beforeText).text().replace(/<>/g,"")`

Comment: It seems to be ok but only for two consecutives spaces. Thanks for your help guys.